# Jersey AsyncResponse and Response

Tags: jersey, jax-rs

I'd like to return a temporaryRedirect, using AsyncResponse.

The following "works" (in that there is no error), but doesn't seem to be asynchronous (it processes one request at a time).

```
    @GET
    public Response doLoad(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @QueryParam("path") String path)  {

        Response response = veryExpensiveOperation(path);
        asyncResponse.resume(response);
        return response;
    }

    private Response veryExpensiveOperation(String path)  {
        // veryExpensiveOperation
    }
```

Should this work?  If I explicitly need to start a new Thread like at https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html#d0e9895, what does returning the Response look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you are using async context properly. From what I see, you are blocking the request processing thread. You are not supposed to block this thread in vertx. How about doing as follows :

```
    @GET
    public void doLoad(@Suspended final AsyncResponse asyncResponse,
            @QueryParam("path") String path)  {

        CompletableFuture<Response> future = veryExpensiveOperation(path);
        future.thenAccept(resp -> asyncResponse.resume(resp));
    }    

    private CompletableFuture<Response> veryExpensiveOperation(String path){
        CompletableFuture<Response> completableFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();

        new Thread(() -> {
            //do expensive stuff here
            completableFuture.complete(Response.ok().entity("Completed").build());
        }).start();

        return completableFuture;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works well with just 1 tweak:  accept(resp) should be resume(resp)?  On your confirmation I'll accept the answer. Thanks again.

Comment: Indeed, it is resume(resp) and not accept(resp) .. I didnt really try the code, just typed in the text editor. Thanks!

Comment: I made the modification.